# Vertical alignment of text in li

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I've been fooling around with HTML/CSS recently, and I'm trying to vertically align the text in an `li` so that it is in the center. I've seen this question (or some variation of it) asked a bunch of times, so I apologize in advance for asking a question I'm sure you're tired of seeing, but I can't get any of the suggested solutions to work. I'm also trying to avoid setting a specific `height`/`line-height` for the `li`, since I'd like this to adjust to the size of the screen.

Here's the HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Experience</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
#nav {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#nav li {
    text-align: center;
    height: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#nav li a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
}

#nav li a:hover {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

I also have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t6ryfqzk/1/) set up in case you'd like to mess around with it and see if you can get it working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `display: table;` on your `li`
and

```
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
```

on your `a`

final styles:

```
#nav li {
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    height: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#nav li a {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Rev 6 of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t6ryfqzk/6/)

Comment: Thanks! I'd tried using `table` and `table-cell` in the past, but I guess I was applying them to the wrong elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can just make the line-height of #nav li 25% of the viewport height like so

```
#nav li {
 text-align: center;
 height: 25%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 line-height: 25vh; /* this is the only thing you need to add */
}
```

It's very simple and short and will work with any changes to the text (like font-size etc) or the list. It doesn't matter how many items you add or remove from the list or what changes you make to the height of the #nav or its list items.
See the [first working revision of your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t6ryfqzk/3/) ;)

Comment: Awesome - thanks for the easy solution! It never crossed my mind that you could use vh for a line-height.

Answer (score 1):

Try these changes in your css

```
#nav li {
    text-align: center;
    height: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;  /* added */
}

#nav li a {
    display: table-cell;  /* changes from block to table-cell */
    vertical-align: middle;  /* added */
    height: 100%;
}
```

See the working example here http://jsfiddle.net/t6ryfqzk/7/

Comment: Thanks for your help! Like I said on another answer, I'd tried doing something similar, but I was using those displays on the wrong elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try making your `li` an `inline-block` if you want them next to eachother, or as block if you want them underneath eachother. Make sure you give the `li` elements a fixed width, and set their text-align as `centered`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I just set the `li` to `display: block`, but that doesn't seem to have changed anything. In terms of the arrangement of the `li`s themself, it looks the way I want it to. I just want to center the links vertically within each `li`. **Edit:** Just saw your comment - no worries!